# Applying style on children does not work in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

Let's say I have this markup:

```
<div class="">
    <p>First text</p>
    <p>
        <span>Hi</span>
        <span class="bold">Bye</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

If I use `text-red-400` on the parent element, I see that all of the children become red.

However, when I use `[&>.bold]:text-red-400`, the span element that has `bold` class won't be changed.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Because `>` CSS selector is [direct children only selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first.

Utility `[&>.bold]:text-red-400` basically is equivalent of

```css
.utility > .bold {
  color: red;
}
```

Every **direct** child with `.bold` class will be red

```html
<div class="[&>.bold]:text-red-400">
    <p class="bold">I'm red</p>
    <p>
        <span>Hi</span>
        <span class="bold">I'm not</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

If you wish to target **every** `.bold` element just remove `>` selector and replace it with underscore `_`

```html
<div class="[&_.bold]:text-red-400">
    <p class="bold">I'm red</p>
    <p>
        <span>Hi</span>
        <span class="bold">Me too</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/AA2PLYA8Fn)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to change the text color for only the span element with bold class then you need to specify the position of the child element as well. You can try the following code:
`[&>*:nth-child(2)]:text-red-500`.
This is mentioned in the tailwind documentation a well for more help: [tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#arbitrary-values-but-for-variants)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks me later.!

```
[&>p]:text-gray-800
```